# Avoid duplicates while union of two result sets

Tags: postgresql, union

I have 2 different queries and their results are as follow:

```
First One:
 user | score | someId 
 ali  |  13   | 12314
      |       | 12323
 veli |  19   | 12345
      |  12   | 12346

Second One:
user  | score | someId 
      |       | 12314
  ali | 12    | 12323
 veli | 19    | 12345
```

My desired output as follow:

```
user  | score | someId 
  ali | 13    | 12314
  ali | 12    | 12323
 veli | 19    | 12345
      |  12   | 12346
```

However the real result is like this:

```
user  | score | someId 
  ali | 13    | 12314
      |       | 12314
  ali | 12    | 12323
 veli | 19    | 12345
      |  12   | 12346
```

Since first and second rows are not the same, distinct function does not solve my problem. If I apply distinct on(someId), then I am losing one of them, which might be the second row in the result. How could I join these conjucate 2 result?

My query is like this:

```
select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.first_game = b.id
union
select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.second_game = b.id
```

**EDIT**

Both user and score field can be null.

Comment: I am not clear. Can you tell what do you want: the one mentioned as **desired output** or the one mentioned as **real result**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not have understood the question correctly but giving it a try.

Lets say your first result is **t1** and second is **t2**. Then the following might do the trick:

```
select coalesce(t1.user, t2.user) as user, 
coalesce(t1.score, t2.score) as score, t1.id 
from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the where clause on both queries and state

```
WHERE a.user IS NOT NULL
```

Another option is to treat the result as a table and write a wrapper over it like

```
SELECT t.user, t.score, t.id 
 FROM (select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.first_game = b.id
       union
       select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.second_game = b.id) t
 WHERE t.user IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I have edited my question so that both user and score field can be null

Comment: It seems that you want everything from the 1st one and from the 2nd one where user is not null? In this case, you are ok with the union and a where clause on the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `DISTINCT ON()`, the order is indeterminate unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Have you tried using the order by clause to ensure that your rows are ordered correctly (basically pick the tie-breaker order)? Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * FROM (
    select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.first_game = b.id
    union
    select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.second_game = b.id
) U
ORDER BY id, user IS NOT NULL DESC, score IS NOT NULL DESC
```

Comment: I have edited my question so that both user and score field can be null

Comment: This should still work though, because it will give you all the distinct id's using a tiebreaker condition specifying that you'd prefer to have non-null users and scores first.

Answer (score 0):

So you just don't want any empty rows?

```
select * from(
select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.first_game = b.id
where b.score is not null
union all
select a.user, b.score, a.id from a join b on a.second_game = b.id 
where b.score is not null
) user_scores
```